# Compare list data using Linq and C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of class, one called lsEmployee and another called lsAccount. The account list is just a list of account names, wheras the employee list has employee and account. I am attempting a linq query to see if the employee’s account matches an account in the account list.

I am new to linq so it’s likely just a syntax issue. I have attempted the following code, but I cannot seem to get this to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
var lsEmployeeAccount = (lsAccount.Where(a => a.Account_Name == employee.Account_Name).SingleOrDefault()).ToString();

string lsEmployeeAccountString = lsEmployeeAccount.ToString() ?? "";

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lsEmployeeAccountString))
{
//If account is not found, do stuff here

}
else
{
//If account is found, do stuff here
}
```

Comment: You can't do it this way. Sicne those are different entities. You probably have to JOIN but not sure unless you post more cod about your lsaccount and lsemployee class

Comment: You have added .ToString() at the end of your query which will fail if the .SingleOrDefault() does not find any matching accounts. See my answer below for an example

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looping through accounts or employees first, but assuming you are going through each employee:

```
foreach(var employee in lsEmployee)
{
  var isExist = lsAccount.Contain(employee.Account_Name);

  if(isExist)
  {}
  else
  {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var lsEmployeeAccount = lsAccount.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Account_Name == employee.Account_Name);
var lsEmployeeAccountString = (lsEmployeeAccount != null) ? lsEmployeeAccount.ToString() : "";

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lsEmployeeAccountString))
{
    //If account is not found, do stuff here
}
else
{
    //If account is found, do stuff here
}
```

But notice that lsEmployeeAccountString might not come out as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the SQL style LINQ syntax when joining multiple `IEnumerable`s containing different kinds of data;  for example:

```
        var validAccounts = new[] {"1234", "2468", "1357", "6789", "9753", "9630"};
        var employees = new[]
        {
            new Employee {Name = "Bob", Account = "1357"},
            new Employee {Name = "Dave", Account = "1030"},
            new Employee {Name = "Fred", Account = "6789"},
            new Employee {Name = "Emma", Account = "2469"},
        };


        var employeesWithValidAccounts =
            from emp in employees
            join validAccount in validAccounts on emp.Account equals validAccount
            select emp.Name;

        foreach (var name in employeesWithValidAccounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

Output:

```
Bob
Fred
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `SingleOrDefault` and there is no matching account then your `lsEmployeeAccount` is null and you will get a NullReferenceException.

Change your comparison to

```
var lsEmployeeAccount = lsAccount.Where(a => a.Account_Name == employee.Account_Name).SingleOrDefault()
if (lsEmployeeAccount == null)
{
    //If account is not found, do stuff here
}
else
{
    //If account is found, do stuff here
}
```

If you didn't need the account then another option would be to

```
if (!lsAccount.Any(a => a.Account_Name == employee.Account_Name))
{
    //If account is not found, do stuff here
}
else
{
    //If account is found, do stuff here
}
```